# How to harmonize Eclipse projects between Windows and Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, eclipse, ubuntu, windows-7

I have a laptop that can dual boot into Windows 7 or Ubuntu. Whenever I use Eclipse on Windows and then boot into Ubuntu or vice versa, Eclipse can't find some of the jar files I'm using for my project. Specifically, `jfxrt.jar`, for JavaFX.

For example, when I use Eclipse on Windows, under Referenced Libraries, it says that the jar file is in `C:\Program Flies\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib`. When I boot into Ubuntu, it still says that the the jar is in `C:\Program Flies\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib`, and surprise surprise, it can't find it. So I change it to the correct location for Ubuntu. It's all well and good until I boot back into Windows, where I have the same problem.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add the jar to the library as an external jar?  That would be the path it stores, then. Use a variable instead if you have to add it manually: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/buildpath/ref-preferences-classpath-variables.htm?cp=1_4_2_0_1_0 .  It's possible, though, that if this is part of Java 7, you just need the latest version of Eclipse--it supports Java 7 explicitly.